# Send iOS push notifications from two apps, but only have one get delivered if user has both apps

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, push

If a user has two of my iOS apps installed (say, a free and a pro version) and I want to make an announcement to all of the users that have either app installed via a push notification, is there a way to prevent two notifications from being delivered to a user if they have both apps installed?

In iOS6 and lower it seems like the push notification token was identical between apps, so it could be used a unique identifier to make sure only one notification was sent to someone. However, as of iOS7 it seems like this was changed so that the push token is unique per app.

Additionally, I do not have any other unique identifiers for a user (such as their email).

The answer to this question might very well be "No". But if that's the case, any references you could cite to support your conclusion would be helpful.

Comment: No. References: "as of iOS7 it seems like this was changed so that the push token is unique per app." and " I do not have any other unique identifiers for a user". Having a unique id wouldn't help anyway - what if the user installs app A and app B are you going to just send the push to one? Which one, what if they installed both but then uninstalled one and you sent it to the uninstalled one, then the user wouldn't get any push at all.

Comment: @MartinH In your example, if we had a unique identifier, we would send it to one app for that user (probably the one most recently used). Then we would poll the APNS Feedback service, if the message was rejected, then we would send it to that person again with the other app.

Comment: How about when the apps send the push tokens they include a payload to say if its originating from the free or the pro version. Then your database would be able to see that two apps have registered using the same token.

Comment: @MartinH The token would be different for each app. As far as I know, there would not be a way to know that it was the same person on both apps.

Comment: Doh, I read this the wrong way round "However, as of iOS7 it seems like this was changed so that the push token is unique per app.". Then  I don't think there's anything that can be done, nothing comes to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is possible after all.

iOS has an iosIdentifierForVendor property which returns a unique identifier for a user tied to the vendor of an application. This can be used to determine if a user has more than one of your apps installed, and thereby only send them notifications from one app.

Answer (score 0):

Remote notification token should be identifier per App, please make sure your free and prod use different App ID, and they will register different token.